# Como checar se processo está aberto e se não estiver, abri-lo?

Tags: vb.net, processo

Olá, estou aprendendo VB.net e gostaria de ajuda.
Estou fazendo um pequeno programinha para checar se um processo está aberto e se não estiver, abri-lo.

cheguei até isso aqui:

```
    Private Sub CheckIfRunning()
    p = Process.GetProcessesByName(TextBox1.Text)
    If p.Length < 1 Then
        Process.Start(TextBox1.Text)
    End If
End Sub
```

O problema é que ele fica abrindo o processo várias vezes, mesmo se já estiver aberto. Alguém pode me ajudar com isso?

Comment: Qual o conteúdo de `TextBox1.Text`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, Sérgio!

Tente da seguinte forma. 
Obs: não sei como está passando o nome do processo, mas o GetProcessesByName tem que receber o nome do processo sem extensão já o Process.Start() precisa da extensão.

```
Private Sub CheckIfRunning()

    Dim p As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(TextBox1.Text))

    If p.Length < 1 Then
        Process.Start(TextBox1.Text)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Oi Matheus, cara deu certo!
Obrigado.